# Bad JSON in Kafka - Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

So, occasionally there's an invalid JSON entry in my Kafka messages coming to my StreamListener. The JSON parser, of course, throws an error, which is great. But, I am using manual acking, so the same message comes back again and throws the error again, etc... Is there a way to automatically ack bad JSON relatively cleanly? As it is, I never actually get the message because the exception is thrown prior to coming into my listener method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but we are defining our error handling story - seems like what you are looking for is a feature where malformed messages (i.e. messages that cannot be extracted will be ignored).

The alternative right now is to skip in-framework conversion, retrieve the String/byte[] payload and do the parsing manually (which is less elegant than the framework-based conversion for sure) - and just ack malformed messages after notifying the error.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. I was just hoping I'd missed something in the docs, I guess. I appreciate it. Is this a feature we could look forward to in the future?